# MUI DataGrid replace Pagination - validateDOMNesting(...): <td> cannot appear as a child of <div>

Tags: reactjs, pagination, datagrid, material-ui

I'm replacing the pagination in the DataGrid component made by Material-UI and get the following console error: `Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <td> cannot appear as a child of <div>`

I don't think I'm doing anything special so I'm wondering what the problem actually is. Am I using the wrong pagination component?

Here's a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-cookies-551oq?file=/src/App.tsx) that reproduces the problem.

I partly use the v5 of MUI, React and Typescript.

```js
import { TablePagination } from "@mui/material";
import { DataGrid, GridColumns } from "@mui/x-data-grid";

export default function App() {
  const columns: GridColumns = [
    {
      field: "foo"
    }
  ];

  const rows = [
    {
      id: "bar"
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div style={{ height: 500 }}>
      <DataGrid
        columns={columns}
        rows={rows}
        components={{ Pagination: TablePagination }}
        componentsProps={{
          pagination: {
            count: 1,
            page: 0,
            onPageChange: () => {},
            rowsPerPage: 10,
            rowsPerPageOptions: [10, 25, 50, 100],
            onRowsPerPageChange: () => {},
            labelRowsPerPage: "Zeilen pro Seite",
            labelDisplayedRows: () => `Seite ${1} von ${1}`,
            nextIconButtonProps: {
              disabled: true
            }
          }
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TablePagination` default component is `td`

mui-datagrid uses divs rather than the `table / tr / td` tag so you have to say the component is a `div` :

```
    componentsProps={{
      pagination: {
        count: 1,
        page: 0,
        component: "div", // here
        onPageChange: () => {},
        rowsPerPage: 10,
        rowsPerPageOptions: [10, 25, 50, 100],
        onRowsPerPageChange: () => {},
        labelRowsPerPage: "Zeilen pro Seite",
        labelDisplayedRows: () => `Seite ${1} von ${1}`,
        nextIconButtonProps: {
          disabled: true
        }
      }
    }}
```

Comment: It worked for me. Excellent answer....

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import {
  DataGrid,
  gridPageCountSelector,
  GridPagination,
  useGridApiContext,
  useGridSelector,
} from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import { useDemoData } from '@mui/x-data-grid-generator';
import MuiPagination from '@mui/material/Pagination';

function Pagination({ page, onPageChange, className }) {
  const apiRef = useGridApiContext();
  const pageCount = useGridSelector(apiRef, gridPageCountSelector);

  return (
    <MuiPagination
      color="primary"
      className={className}
      count={pageCount}
      page={page + 1}
      onChange={(event, newPage) => {
        onPageChange(event, newPage - 1);
      }}
    />
  );
}

function CustomPagination(props) {
  return <GridPagination ActionsComponent={Pagination} {...props} />;
}

export default function CustomPaginationGrid() {
  const { data } = useDemoData({
    dataSet: 'Commodity',
    rowLength: 100,
    maxColumns: 6,
  });

  return (
    <Box sx={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
      <DataGrid
        pagination
        slots={{
          pagination: CustomPagination,
        }}
        {...data}
        initialState={{
          ...data.initialState,
          pagination: { paginationModel: { pageSize: 25 } },
        }}
      />
    </Box>
  );
}
```